# Add padding to select, but not option tags

Tags: html, css

I have a simple `select` dropdown menu with a significant amount of `padding-left` and `padding-right`:

If you click the `select` input, you'll notice the `option` tags also have the same amount of `padding-left` and `padding-right` applied. However, I want the padding to only apply to the `select` tag, but not the `option` tags (i.e. no padding for the `option` tags).

How can I do this?

```css
select {
  width: 400px;
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 12px 48px;
}
```

```html
<select>
 <option>Option 1</option>
 <option>Option 2</option>
 <option>Option 3</option>
 <option>Option 4</option>
 <option>Option 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This appears in Chrome, not Firefox.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://codepen.io/rcdesign/pen/GexmJ

Comment: if you want different style for option you can use `select > option` .

Comment: As for a lot of browser-related questions: you want this behavior, but do your users want it? Seems that Webkit does not allow styling options, so it aligns the option's text to the select's text. Overriding this behavior might break some displays (like mobile, which have other ways to implement select's drop-downs), screen-readers etc.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know the select box and the dropdown get rendered by the browser engine. This means they are not changeable.

So the only solution is to use a framework (Because of this reason there are many outside) or build one by your own.

If you look in the developer console you will also see that most of the styles of the option element are inherited by the browser and greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sel').click(function(){
        $('ul').toggle();
    })

    $('li').click(function(){
        $('.sel input[type=text]').val($(this).html());
        $('ul').hide();
    })
})
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sel {
    position: relative;
    width: inherit;
    border: 1px solid #000;

}

.sel input[type="text"]{
    width: 100%;
    background: lightgray;
    padding: 12px 48px;
    border-style: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sel span {
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    top: 10px;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: lightgray;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
}

li {
   padding: 10px 0;
}

li:hover {
    background-color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sel">
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="Option1"><span>▼</span>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li>Option1</li>
        <li>Option2</li>
        <li>Option3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```